# How do I define dependency among kernel modules?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

How one can define a dependency for modules in kernel,

Example:

```
got module1 and module2.
```

How do I say say kernel `module2` should be loaded after `module1` or `module2` is dependent of `module1`?

Note : module2 is not using any symbol from module1, but still order is important in my use case. so don't relate with moddep in kernel.

Comment: Cant we do it manually ?

Comment: @srinivasth Can you provide more info on the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: possible duplicate of [External Linux kernel module dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237871/external-linux-kernel-module-dependencies)

Comment: Are you talking about external modules (aka files), or built-in modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For easy solution, you can add symbol in first module and check that symbol in second module init. If symbol is not exported using

```
EXPORT_SYMBOL
```

you can return from second module initialization  itself.

For details, from header

```
      Linux kernel modules can provide services (called "symbols") for other
   modules to use (using one of the EXPORT_SYMBOL variants in the code).
   If a second module uses this symbol, that second module clearly depends
   on the first module. These dependencies can get quite complex.

   depmod creates a list of module dependencies by reading each module
   under /lib/modules/version and determining what symbols it exports and
   what symbols it needs. By default, this list is written to modules.dep,
   and a binary hashed version named modules.dep.bin, in the same
   directory. If filenames are given on the command line, only those
   modules are examined (which is rarely useful unless all modules are
   listed).  depmod also creates a list of symbols provided by modules in
   the file named modules.symbols and its binary hashed version,
   modules.symbols.bin. Finally, depmod will output a file named
   modules.devname if modules supply special device names (devname) that
   should be populated in /dev on boot (by a utility such as udev).
```

Answer (score 14):

As of the linux 4.4 kernel (and maybe earlier) soft dependencies can be used to specify that a kernel module be loaded before or after a module is requested to be loaded.  Those soft dependencies can be setup in a configuration file as described in the modprobe.d (5) manpage, or they can be specified directly in the code for the kernel module directly using the `MODULE_SOFTDEP` macro.

To accomplish loading `module2` after `module1` by modifying the code of `module2`, add this line outside of a function to the `module2` code:

`MODULE_SOFTDEP("pre: module1")`

To accomplish the same by modifying the `module1` code, you would use this line:

`MODULE_SOFTDEP("post: module2")`

Comment: It should be noted, that if module1 is a built-in, then all bets are off using the "MODULE_SOFTDEP" macro, and you are probably better off using a deferred probe, or maybe faking/creating some kind of dependency of module1 on a symbol in module2.

Answer (score 5):

Quote from man page of depmod:

```
   Linux kernel modules can provide services (called "symbols") for other
   modules to use (using one of the EXPORT_SYMBOL variants in the code).
   If a second module uses this symbol, that second module clearly depends
   on the first module. These dependencies can get quite complex.

   depmod creates a list of module dependencies by reading each module
   under /lib/modules/version and determining what symbols it exports and
   what symbols it needs. By default, this list is written to modules.dep,
   and a binary hashed version named modules.dep.bin, in the same
   directory. If filenames are given on the command line, only those
   modules are examined (which is rarely useful unless all modules are
   listed).  depmod also creates a list of symbols provided by modules in
   the file named modules.symbols and its binary hashed version,
   modules.symbols.bin. Finally, depmod will output a file named
   modules.devname if modules supply special device names (devname) that
   should be populated in /dev on boot (by a utility such as udev).
```